# How to compare a ZonedDateTime's time with another ZonedDateTime but with only time and not date?

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I have two dates in my Local Time time.

`"2021-09-01 07:00:00 AM"` and `"2021-09-01 08:00:00 AM"` (PST)

I'm trying to check if these two dates are between two times, `8 am` and `10 pm` of another time zone. (EST)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
ZonedDateTime startLocal = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-09-01 07:00:00 AM", formatter).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime endLocal = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-09-01 08:00:00 AM", formatter).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

ZonedDateTime startEst = startLocal.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
ZonedDateTime endEst = endLocal.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

System.out.println("Start Est: " + startEst.format(formatter)); //Start Est: 2021-09-01 10:00:00 AM
System.out.println("End Est: " + endEst.format(formatter)); //End Est: 2021-09-01 11:00:00 AM
```

I'm stuck on how I can compare the starting time zones, `startEst` and `endEst` with the two times `8 am` and `10 pm` without the use of a `date` and only using the time.

I've added two more `ZonedDateTimes` to compare

```
ZonedDateTime buisnessStartHoursInEst8am = //Unsure of what to use here
ZonedDateTime buisnessEndHoursInEst10pm = //Unsure of what to use here
```

```
if(startEst.isBefore(buisnessStartHoursInEst8am)){
     System.out.println("Business has not opened yet");
}

if(endEst.isAfter(buisnessEndHoursInEst10pm)){
     System.out.println("Business has already closed");
}
```

Comment: ... to an extent, you only _can_ compare times with a date attached - remember in the US that DST is a thing, and so whether any given time is between two others in another time zone will depend on what the given date is.  If you're trying to do something like the display the open/close schedule for the current week, you'd create the start/end times for the given dates, and check with the listed methods - is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.

1. You should parse the strings to `LocalDateTime` as they do not have a timezone.
2. Convert them to `ZonedDateTime`, which you have not done correctly. You should use `LocalDateTime#atZone` to do so.

Finally, convert the obtained `ZonedDateTime`s to the `ZonedDateTime`s in the EST timezone and then do the comparison. For getting the `buisnessStartHoursInEst8am` and `buisnessEndHoursInEst10pm`, use `ZonedDateTime#withHours`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime startLocal = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-09-01 07:00:00 AM", formatter);
        LocalDateTime endLocal = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-09-01 08:00:00 AM", formatter);

        ZoneId zoneLA = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
        ZoneId zoneNY = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

        ZonedDateTime startZdtPst = startLocal.atZone(zoneLA);
        ZonedDateTime endZdtPst = endLocal.atZone(zoneLA);

        ZonedDateTime startZdtEst = startZdtPst.withZoneSameInstant(zoneNY);
        ZonedDateTime endZdtEst = endZdtPst.withZoneSameInstant(zoneNY);

        ZonedDateTime buisnessStartHoursInEst8am = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneNY).withHour(8);
        ZonedDateTime buisnessEndHoursInEst10pm = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneNY).withHour(22);

        // Compare
        if (startZdtEst.isBefore(buisnessStartHoursInEst8am)) {
            System.out.println("Business has not opened yet");
        }

        if (endZdtEst.isAfter(buisnessEndHoursInEst10pm)) {
            System.out.println("Business has already closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> I have two dates in my Local Time time.
>
> "2021-09-01 07:00:00 AM" and "2021-09-01 08:00:00 AM" (PST)

That first sentence appears to be a misunderstanding. A `LocalTime` object holds only a time-of-day, without a date. Perhaps you meant `LocalDateTime`, which holds a date and time-of-day, but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

While your the body of your Question is unclear, let's address the specifics of your title:

> How to compare a ZonedDateTime's time with another ZonedDateTime but with only time and not date?

To compare to `ZonedDateTime` objects by their time-of-day only, ignoring the date and ignoring the time zone, just extract `LocalTime` objects.

```
ZonedDateTime edmonton = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ) ;
ZonedDateTime tunis = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;

LocalTime edmontonTime = edmonton.toLocalTime() ;
LocalTime tunisTime = tunis.toLocalTime() ;

boolean isEdmontonEarlierThanTunis = edmontonTime.isBefore( tunisTime ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/p8jdZ5).

```
2021-09-01T15:13:55.380552-06:00[America/Edmonton]
2021-09-01T22:13:55.384061+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
isEdmontonEarlierTimeThanTunis: true  edmontonTime: 15:13:55.380552 tunisTime: 22:13:55.384061
```

Comment: I don't believe you've answered the question.  OP wants to convert his ZonedDateTime from one time zone into a LocalTime for a different zone, for the purpose of the comparison.

Comment: I think he wants to compare the instants, i.e. adjust the local dates to EST.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The title is quite clear while the body is not: *How to compare a ZonedDateTime's time with another ZonedDateTime but with only time and not date?* I answered that query. Perhaps I should have simply voted to close as unclear rather than  post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite ambiguous but I will try to give you an example of how I can check the difference of the same time in different zone in addition to printing Time only

Create two Zone ids

create a LocalDateTime

create ZoneDateTime which need both the zone and LocalDateTime.
after that just invoke withZoneSameInstant and choose other Zone,

here it will print full LocalDateTime once again invoke toLocalTime to get the time only

```
        ZoneId nYork = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        ZoneId tokyo = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo");

        LocalDateTime randomLDT = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 9, 22, 07, 00);

        ZonedDateTime selectFirstZone = ZonedDateTime.of(randomLDT, nYork);

        System.out.println(selectFirstZone.withZoneSameInstant(tokyo).toLocalTime());
```